# at the age of... vs. at an age of

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

A quote from The Guardian:

> For it is mercilessly clear that when Porter died last year at **the**
>   age of 55, he was at the height of his powers.

Should the definite article always be used when a single cardinal number is used in the expression "at the/an age of.." ? Or "AN" is also acceptable if the sentence does not refer to a definite person, like, say "students tend to graduate at an age of 22"?

I find numerous examples of "at an age of" and it's hard to sense the pattern of usage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

“At the age of” is the idiomatic phrasing. It [very strongly dominates](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+the+age+of%2Cat+an+age+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) “at an age of”.

Browsing through [published occurrences of “at an age of”](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22at%20an%20age%20of%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en), I see mostly scientific and legal publications.

“At an age of” is also preferable to express an unspecified point in an age range, as in [“plant growth stops at an age of between 100 and 500 years”](http://books.google.com/books?id=E9G6bIZirnoC&pg=PA65&dq=%22at+an+age+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=D-0DUtgNzcC0BqDbgKAK&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAzgK) or [“Walking difficulties are often detected already at an age of 1–3 years”](http://books.google.com/books?id=Mrj5OTkEk4YC&pg=PA87&dq=%22at+an+age+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=t-0DUv-VD4jysgbO9oHwDA&ved=0CCwQ6AEwADge). Using “at the age of” would indicate that the statement applies to the whole range rather than one point within the range.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on context. General rule of thumb, though, is the is definite, meaning, an event happened exactly when that person was that age. Usually, it's for a single person. An is more generalized, used to mean around, about, or average of for a group of people.